# Eureka Client unable to send heartbeat sometimes

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am having sporadic logs coming up which tell me that the Eureka client is not able to send its heartbeat to the Eureka server. The registration works fine and its able to send 95% of its heartbeats. I only see the sporadic failing calls in instances which do not run on the same virtual machine as eureka does.

We updated Spring boot to 2.1.2 and using the bom with the Greenwich.RELEASE(before we were using Finchley.RELEASE). With the Finchley.RELEASE we have seen this logs very rarely if any.

The client config in application.yml

```
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    ip-address: ${HOSTNAME}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://my-eureka:8761/eureka/
```

If I output the gradle dependencies I see that the http client was bumped to the latest bugfix version: 4.5.7

```
+--- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:1.19.1
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1 -> 4.5.7
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.11
|    |    |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11
|    |    |    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.19.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3 -> 4.5.7 (*)
```

The logs I see:

```
05:26:20.527 [AsyncResolver-bootstrap-executor-0] INFO  c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver - Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
05:31:20.528 [AsyncResolver-bootstrap-executor-0] INFO  c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver - Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
05:36:20.528 [AsyncResolver-bootstrap-executor-0] INFO  c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver - Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
05:41:20.529 [AsyncResolver-bootstrap-executor-0] INFO  c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver - Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
05:41:33.949 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] INFO  o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://my-eureka:8761: The target server failed to respond
05:41:33.949 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] INFO  o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Retrying request to {}->http://my-eureka:8761
05:42:03.953 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] ERROR c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient - Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://my-eureka:8761/eureka/}
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: my-eureka:8761 failed to respond
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
        at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:529)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:102)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:89)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1405)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: my-eureka:8761 failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:294)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:230)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:679)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:481)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
        ... 26 common frames omitted
05:42:03.954 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] WARN  c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient - Request execution failed with message: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: my-eureka:8761 failed to respond
05:42:03.956 [DiscoveryClient-HeartbeatExecutor-0] INFO  c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient - Request execution succeeded on retry #1
05:46:20.529 [AsyncResolver-bootstrap-executor-0] INFO  c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver - Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

Comment: This is happening for me too. Have you found something about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with the jersey client, try excluding the jersey dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```